# Passing ViewModel through TempData?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities

I need to maintain my ViewModel data when doing a Redirect to Action.  I understand I can do this using tempdata, but I'm not sure what that looks like.  Here is my re-direct:

```
if(StateList == "MN" && PorR == "Purchase")
                {
                    TempData["calculationViewModel"] = calculationViewModel;
                    return RedirectToAction("MNPurchase");
                }
```

Once I re-direct to the action MNPurchase, how do I create a ViewModel out of the TempData?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var calculationModel=(CalculationViewModel)TempData["calculationViewModel"];
```

You should cast it to your model Type. Otherwise it will be object.

Answer (score 0):

```
var calculationViewModel = TempData["calculationViewModel"];
```